# Reversing indices names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following df

```
                  b
      GRE*BLU   0.000383
      RED*CLE   0.000330
      BRO*BLA   0.000426
```

How can I turn it to :

```
                    b
      BLU*GRE   0.000383
      CLE*RED   0.000330
      BLA*BRO   0.000426
```

I just would like to reverse the order of the index (instead of `RED*CLE` , `CLE*RED` and so on). It is possible too do so?

My apologize, the previous example wasn't correct, the idea is to reverse strings  not characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python strings can be reversed using the extended slice syntax:

```
mystring[::-1]
```

Select the data frame's index & apply the above, assigning back to the dataframe's index:

```
df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: x[::-1])
```

**note: edit following edit of original post:**

split the index string on the `*` character, reverse the list & join back:

```
df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: '*'.join(x.split('*')[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new index from the list of reversed elements in the original index.

```
df.index = pd.Index([row[::-1] for row in df.index])
            b
B*A  0.000383
C*A  0.000330
C*B  0.000426
```

You can also do this with a vectorized NumPy function (which will be much faster as your number of rows gets large):

```
rev = np.vectorize(lambda x: x[::-1])
df.index = rev(df.index)
```

**Update**

Per your updated question:

```
rev = np.vectorize(lambda x: '*'.join(x.split('*')[::-1]))
                b
BLU*GRE  0.000383
CLE*RED  0.000330
BLA*BRO  0.000426
```